# Excel list VBA concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

Image below shows an Excel list I have. Columns A-C is the contents I have. Columns D and E is the result I'm looking for. I've manually entered it to show the result.

[image: Excel list]

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub New_SKU()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

'figure out how far down data goes
Dim endrow As Long
Dim currentrow As Long
Dim basename

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Blad1")

With ws
    endrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   'always start in the correct column
    .Cells(.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Row, "B").Activate

   'loop through all data
    Do While ActiveCell.Row < endrow

       'loop through empty cells and set formula if cell isn't empty
        Do While ActiveCell.Row <= endrow

          'if next cell isn't empty, isn't past the end of the list, go to outer loop
            If ActiveCell.Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then

                basename = Selection.Address

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'            If ActiveCell.Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'            If ActiveCell.Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'            If ActiveCell.Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'            If ActiveCell.Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'            If ActiveCell.Formula = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula <> "" And ActiveCell.Row <= endrow Then
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & basename & ",""-""," & "C" & Selection.Row & ")"
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & basename & ""
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

           Else
               Exit Do
           End If
'           End If
'           End If
'           End If
'           End If
'           End If
        Loop
     Loop

End With

End Sub
```

I am reusing code from a similar problem I received help with earlier.

My first problem:

If uncomment the If-statements, when I start the script Excel goes blank (white) and stalls immediatly.

Running the script in its current state (If-satements commented out), I can see that I get the correct result in cell D2 and then cell B3 is selected (keep in mind that there are no results in column D or E), and then the screen goes blank and Excel stalls. I do not get any result in column E.

Since there are variation in sizes (column C), it can vary from 2-3 to 5-6.

I cannot figure out why I won't receive a result in E-column and why it stalls and goes white.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bit hard to follow that, but I think easier to fill in the blanks and then just use concatenate formulas all the way down. You don't even need VBA for that.

Comment: Just to elaborate, one reason why the code is a bit difficult to follow and probably tricky for you to disentangle is the use of Select and Activate. Avoid if at all possible, and this usually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment above, here is a different approach

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long

Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"

For r = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(r, 4).Value = Cells(r, 2).Value & "-" & Cells(r, 3).Value
    Cells(r, 5).Value = Cells(r, 2).Value
Next r

Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a non-VBA answer, you can paste this formula in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(B2="",LEFT(D1,FIND("-",D1)-1)&"-"&C2,B2&"-"&C2)
```